# How to update a multi document yaml file on condition using yq?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm, yq

I am trying to add namespace to a multi document kubernetes yaml file if it doesn't exist but if the namespace field already exists don't update it using yq but i can't seem to get it to work. Is this possible?

e.g.

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: serviceaccount1
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: serviceaccount2
  namespace: namespace2
```

should end up something like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: serviceaccount1
  namespace: namespace1
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: serviceaccount2
  namespace: namespace2
```

**UPDATE:**

After successfully updating the yaml file thanks to:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74736018/16126608

I am getting the namespace populated however due to the fact my yaml file was produced as an output of a helm template I am seeing the following issue where an empty document is having {} added as a result of the yq command, e.g.

```yaml
---
# Source: path/to/chart/templates/configmap.yaml
---
# Source: ppath/to/chart/templates/network-policy.yaml
---
```

Is coming out like this afterwards:

```yaml
---
# Source: path/to/chart/templates/configmap.yaml
---
{}
# Source: path/to/chart/templates/network-policy.yaml
---
{}
```

Is it possible to have yq to not add the {} and ignore the empty documents?

I am using mikefarah/yq

Answer (score 2):

You can use `has` to check the existence of a field, and `not` to negate, then `select` it and add the new field.

[Which implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info) of `yq` are you using?

Using [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq):

```bash
yq -y 'select(.metadata | has("namespace") | not).metadata.namespace = "namespace1"'
```

Using [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq):

```bash
yq 'select(.metadata | has("namespace") | not) |= .metadata.namespace = "namespace1"'
```

Comment: Thanks that worked a treat for adding the namespace, I am now seeing an issue where it is updating empty documents and I have updated the original question above if you know how to fix or prevent that from happening?